# How to pull a certain bit of info from a one input answer

Tags: java

i hope the title made sense. sorry i am a student taking a cs class where we are using java and i cannot seem to get this part of the program correct. so what we are doing is writing a program that asks a person for their name and address and it plugs that info into a junk mail letter that they would receive in the mail. what i have so far is

```
String name;
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println ("Enter name: ");
    name = scan.nextLine();

    String add;
    System.out.println ("Enter street address: ");
    add = scan.nextLine();

    String add2;
    System.out.println ("Enter city, state abbreviation and zip code: ");
    add2 = scan.nextLine();

    System.out.println (" ");
    System.out.println (" ");
    System.out.println ("Dear " + name + ",");
    System.out.println ("   Congratulations! You are a finalist in a sweepstakes to win ");
    System.out.println ("$1,000,000! You may soon be the richest of your neighbors on ");
    System.out.println (add.substring(4) + "! You will be the talk of " + add2.substring(0,13) + ". To claim your ");
    System.out.println ("prize simply return the enclosed envelope. " + name.substring(4,7).toUpperCase() + ", DO NOT PASS UP THIS");
    System.out.println ("FABULOUS OFFER!");
    System.out.println(" ");
    System.out.println ("Sincerely, ");
    System.out.println ("I. M. Aswindler");
    System.out.println ("Sweepstakes Coordinator");
    System.out.println ("");
```

basically what i need to do with this is pull out certain bits of information and plug it into the letter. i have it working using substrings, but that only works if you use a specific name. i need it to be able to pull Mr./Mrs. out of what they input, be able to pull the street name out (without the house number), and such. i hope this makes sense and i hope someone is able to help me. im having a lot of trouble trying to figure it out. thanks!

Comment: Look at regular expressions.

Comment: You can use string.split() to breakup first and last name.  You can also use it to break up an address.

Answer (score 1):

A few things.

<strike>Declare your vars at the top for small programs like this. Makes it much more readable.</strike>

`String name, add, city, state, zip`   Sorry, this was my personal preference, no idea if its standard.

You can easily solve this program by just asking for each piece of info individually. Ask for and put them all into their own String variables, and then call the strings in your output.
However, you can also use `trim()` and `replaceAll` to make it that your program can handle almost any input. I'll show you what I mean by doing that for Name and Address.

**Name:**

You should watch for white space. If I run your program and put in
 `'            firstname       lastname` as the input, the result is  `Dear       firstname       lastname,`, which is pretty ugly.
You could `.trim()` your `scan.nextline()`, to make it get rid of the beginning and ending whitespace.

You can also use replaceAll to get rid of the whitespace between the firstname and lastname. For example

`'           FirstName             Lastname            '`
would output to `Dear FirstName LastName` if you use `name = ((scan.nextLine()).trim()).replaceAll("( )+", " ");`

**Address**

The way you use substrings and indexes is a bit messy. Ideally, you want to handle whitespaces, long numbers, etc.
Once again, trim all the whitespace using

`VarName = ((scan.nextLine()).trim()).replaceAll("( )+", " ");`

Then, you want to isolate the street name correct? You can do this by searching for the space between the Street Number and the street address. You can do this by using `add.substring(add.indexOf(" ")+1,add.length())`

If you set that to a var, say streetName, it would take start from the first space (+1 so it actually begins at the first char of the street name) and goes all the way to the end of the string.

Example input:    `38    Banana Court`

If you call `System.out.println("$1,000,000! You may soon be the richest of your neighbors on " + streetName);`

Output: `Banana Court`

**The Rest**

I think you can solve the rest by yourself. Probably would be best to call City, State, Zipcode seperatly unless you want to spend more time messing around with substrings. Remember to use trim and replaceAll to get rid of the white space.

**Heres an example program that should show you what im talking about above.**

`String name, address, streetName, city, state, zip;
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("What is your name?");
        name = ((scan.nextLine()).trim()).replaceAll("( )+", " ");
        System.out.println(name);
        System.out.println("What is your address?");
        address = ((scan.nextLine()).trim()).replaceAll("( )+", " ");
        streetName = address.substring(address.indexOf(" ")+1,address.length());
        System.out.println("Your Street Address is :" + streetName);`

Run it, try inputs with white spaces and such. It should help you finish the rest quickly.

Comment: Good stuff. Except for the variable declarations. This aint Pascal no more, so it would be clearer to just define and initialize them straight off, like `String name = scan.nextLIne().trim().replaceAll("\\s+"," ");`
Although Demeter might have something to say about it then...

Comment: @KoosGadellaa Sorry. Vars at the top is my personal preference for short programs such as this,  I can see why its not acceptable elsewhere.